# Integrating revolut payment with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, payment

I am getting this sort of error while integrating flutter with revolut by following this doc.
[docs](https://developer.revolut.com/docs/accept-payments/tutorials/accept-payments-via-revolut-pay2/android#1-install-android-sdk)

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not find com.revolut:revolutpay:2.1.0.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/revolut/revolutpay/2.1.0/revolutpay-2.1.0.pom
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/revolut/revolutpay/2.1.0/revolutpay-2.1.0.pom
> > - https://jitpack.io/com/revolut/revolutpay/2.1.0/revolutpay-2.1.0.pom
> > - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/revolut/revolutpay/2.1.0/revolutpay-2.1.0.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :app

i tried adding  **maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }** and **jcenter()** inside allprojects>repositories in project level build.gradle but this did not work.

Comment: and the issue was with "com.revolut:revolutpay:2.1.0" in docs which I have overridden with  "com.revolut:revolutpay:2.2" after viewing this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.revolut/revolutpay